# Accessing Jenkins server and building pipelines from another PC (without remote desktop)

Tags: jenkins

Currently I have a jenkins installation running as a service on a server PC, and I have an admin user, with another user. The server is where I would like all of my pipelines to run.
I'd like to be able to somehow access jenkins with another PC (my own laptop), without needing to remotedesk/anydesk to the server PC every time I want to build or change a pipeline.

The reason I am not using my own laptop as the master/controller, and the server PC as an agent, is because I'd like pipelines to have the capability to run instantly, at any time, when there is a commit to a github repo (e.g. when my laptop is off, it will not run).

I've explored some options but haven't really found an alternative to using remotedesk. The reason why I am reluctant to use this is because in my mind it defeats the purpose of having multiple users.

Thanks

Comment: Jenkins has web UI, right?

Answer (score 0):

To access Jenkins from server PC: http://localhost:8080
To access Jenkins from another PC: http://server_PC_IP:8080
Note: Add a rule in the firewall for the port 8080.